# not able to pass $event on click of on-timespan-click in mwl-calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I am using mwl-calendar. 
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar
I want to pass $event on click of any day. So I used

```
on-timespan-click="vm.timespanClicked(domEvent,calendarDate)"
```

and changed

```
ng-click=vm.calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)
```

to

```
ng-click=vm.calendarCtrl.dateClicked($event,day.date)
```

in angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min

But still this is showing it undefined.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to pass it like this:

```
<mwl-calendar
        events="events"
        view="calendarView"
        view-title="calendarTitle"
        view-date="viewDate"
        on-timespan-click="timespanClicked($event, calendarDate)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar>
```

and than in your directive

```
scope.timespanClicked = function(event, date){
                    console.log(event);
                    console.log(date);
                };
```

and you can work with the $event and date from here. Hope this helps.